# Unable to reference the res/colors file - Eclipse

Tags: android

I'm using Eclipse.

**Problem**: Code that references colors in my resource folder can't be launched.

**Example**:

```
--><LinearLayout 

`android:background="@color/background"` // I don't have the color directory. How do I get it. (that code refers to color in my project/res folder)



  android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained by L0rdAli3n and *CommonsWare*, there's no default colors file available - you have to create your own. Same as you create layout to give an example.

Here's an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <!-- A COLOR NAMED background with value #FFFFFF in #RRGGBB hex value-->
  <color name="background">#FFFFFF</color>
  <!-- A COLOR NAMED mycolor with value #FFF in #RGB value-->
  <color name="mycolor">#FFF</color>
  <!-- A COLOR NAMED mycolor2 with value #00FFFFFF in #ARGB [A= ALPHA]value-->
  <color name="mycolor2">#00FFFFFF</color>
</resources>
```

There are currently three formats specified above which are supported. You can include this XML (without the resources tag) in Strings.xml which is in you res/values/ folder. And can straight away use them  `with @[:packagename]color/[colorname]`

Alternatively you can create a colors.xml file in you res/values/ folder and use same as above, this is recommended and best practiced approach.

Answer (score 4):

There is no `color` directory. You put color resources in `res/values/colors.xml`, as is indicated in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Color).

Answer (score 1):

You just create the "res/color"-Folder and put your xml-Files in it.

You find more infos about colors in the documentation:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Color

Comment: @L0rdAlien: There is no `res/color` folder in Android.

Comment: Right, mixed it up with ColorStateLists which you put in the res/color-Folder ...

Comment: it is available https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html